# How do I create new user from scratch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-management

I'm still working on my very first Ruby on Rails project. The latest issue I'm dealing with is the user management system. I tried using Devise but I couldn't get past a certain error so I decided to create my sign in/login system manually. I'm using Ruby 3.0.2 w/ Rails 7.0.0alpha2.

I got a lot farther this manual way but I'm getting 'undefined method `cost' for BCrypt::Engine:Class' I've googled and they mention changing the version of bcrypt, I did with no luck

They mention going to my user_controller and changing my create method from old code to this '@user = User.new(user_params)' doing this changed my error from 'forbidden' to the error I'm currently writing to you about.

Not to sure on where my issue is, my guess is somewhere in the model or controller, thank your for your time!

User Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create

    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thank your for signing up!"
    else
      flash[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render "new"
    end

  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

end
```

Session Controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])

    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "logged in!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Email or passwrod is invalid"
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end
end
```

User Model

```
require 'bcrypt'

class User < ApplicationRecord
  include BCrypt
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
  has_secure_password

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

end
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'sessions/new'
  resources :users, only: [:new, :create]
  resources :fighters
  resources :sessions
  get 'home/about'
  root 'home#index'
  get 'signup', to: 'users#new', as: 'signup'
  get 'login', to: 'sessions#new', as: 'login'
  get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'logout'


end
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv1dl.png)

[User Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCHqE.png)

[User Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6wlD.png)

[Routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4alM.png)

[Session Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0L97.png)

Comment: And when you say you changed the version of bcrypt, what did you do, exactly? Avoid being vague in your descriptions -- most new users of this site (and some experienced ones) forget that the people reading your post are not sitting next to you and cannot see what you can see. Furthermore, when we need to ask for clarification, it's not a simple matter of turning to the person sitting next to you and asking a question. You have to be thorough and precise in your descriptions, or you'll just waste time and people will get bored and wander off without answering your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MarsAtomic, thanks for the feedback, I'll work on that. 
When I changed the version, I went to my gemfile and then did a 'bundle update'. Are the screenshots of my code showing?

Comment: Is there some tutorial you're following to put this system together? I haven't looked at the Hartl tutorial for years, but I seem to recall the author favoring a roll your own approach to authentication for your first app. Is that what you're using?

Comment: @MarsAtomic yes I'm using https://youtu.be/fmyvWz5TUWg "Learn Ruby On Rails - Full Course" - FreeCodeCamp.org. 2:02 in the course they start using devise, due to the errors I was getting I started googling user management from scratch and started building on my own from there.

Comment: I see. But did you rely on any tutorials for the user management portion of your app? This is the important bit, since it's the part that seems to be failing.

Comment: @MarsAtomic I googled and found a written tutorial that i followed to fill out sessions/user controller etc. but I couldn't find the source again to send to you. I did end up resolving my issues in my answer below. I thank you for your time and helping me properly ask questions on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

I logged on this morning and all of a sudden my problem was fixed! Maybe something having to do with the terminal closing because I compared the code I posted here and what I have in my files, very little changes.

1 change I made was adding @ to 'session[:user_id] = user.id' to make '@user.id'

After I was able to log on, I was getting an error to log off. The change I made was adding 'session.clear' and 'redirect_to login_path' in my destroy method.

Both changes made in my sessions_controller.rb

I also added "delete 'sessions', to: 'session#destroy'" to routes.rb